# Checkbox insert 1 or 0 into SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, pdo

I am setting up a system that has many answers from a question. Therefore the user can click a button to dynamically add answers. I want the user to be able to tick a checkbox next to the answers which are correct and then insert this into the database (1 being correct).

Here is what I have:

HTML:

```
<div id="answers">
 <label class="answer">
  Answer:
   <input type="text" name="ab_name[]" value=""/>
    Correct?
   <input type="checkbox" name="ab_correct[]" value="0">
 </label>
</div>
```

PHP

```
$ab_name = $_POST['ab_name'];
$ab_correct = $_POST['ab_correct'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO answers_bank (`ab_name`, `ab_correct` ) VALUES (:ab_name, :ab_correct )";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

foreach ($_POST['ab_name'] as $ab_name) {
$stmt->bindValue(':ab_name', $ab_name);
$stmt->bindValue(':ab_correct', $ab_correct);
$stmt->execute();
}
```

Like this:

[image: This should give more of an idea:]

The SQL inserts the `ab_name` but the `ab_correct` is ALWAYS set to `1` if it is ticked or unticked. Any guidance on this please?

Comment: You're not looping through the $ab_correct array though.

Comment: If `ab_correct` is not checked it won't be sent, are you running JS to check for that? `$ab_correct` and `$_POST['ab_correct']` are arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `for` loop instead of the `foreach`. Well, first of all, you need to make sure both arrays has the same amount of elements.

```
if(count($_POST['ab_name']) != count($_POST['ab_correct']))
    exit('Not same amount of elements.');
```

Then, loop through each of them.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['ab_name']); $i++){
    $stmt->bindValue(':ab_name', $_POST['ab_name'][$i]);
    $stmt->bindValue(':ab_correct', $_POST['ab_correct'][$i]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It does not reach the exit statement which is good. However I receive: "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"

Comment: Oops, you have to add `$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);` in the for loop to reset the binding every time.

Comment: Turns out it was me placing my SQL after the for loop rather than before. Answer has been solved thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['$ab_correct'])){$update = 1;}else{$update = 0;}

foreach ($_POST['ab_name'] as $ab_name) {
$stmt->bindValue(':ab_name', $ab_name);
$stmt->bindValue(':ab_correct', $update);
$stmt->execute();

}
```

Comment: Thanks - this is what I was going for, it seems that if one of the checkboxes is ticked, it will insert 1 for all of the answers which I don't understand